# Which login module is called by WebSphere when j_security_check is called?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jaas

I have written a custom login module and called it in navigator (application login module for content navigator), and it runs very well, but it doesn't work on the login page when we call the j_security_check url.

Is there a way, I can configure it there? Since it is a jsp page I will get much more things to do .

Answer (score 1):

If you use j_security_check, then it will go to the `WEB_INBOUND` login module. Check this page [Developing custom login modules for a system login configuration for JAAS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_jaascustlogmod.html?lang=en) for more details. However sometimes it is better to provide your own login method, make a copy of `WEB_INBOUND` and customize that copy with inserting your own login module. Depends on your requirement and other applications installed on the server.

Comment: Thanks I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Your login JSP should point to j_security_check. Username and password should be named j_username and j_password, respectively.
If your custom login module is configured correctly in WAS, it should get username and password from this login page.

Here is an example of login JSP:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/j_security_check">
            <table width="80%">
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" align="right">Username:</td>
                <td><input size="20" type="text" name="j_username" maxlength="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:</td>
                <td><input size="20" type="password" name="j_password" maxlength="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Login">&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, you have to define auth method, login and loginerror JSPs, together with security roles. This is defined in web.xml of your web application.

This is an example of a simple login config where all authenticated users are allowed to access protected resource (you have to change servlet name according to your setup):

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>loginerror.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>users</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>appServlet</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Note: if your JSPs reside inside WEB-INF, you cannot access it directly, in that cas you should have a server-side controller that redirects it to these JSPs.

Lastly, you have to define security role mapping users that maps e.g. to all authenticated users.

This is defined in EAR binding file ibm-application-bnd.xml (put it into EAR's META-INF directory next to application.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <security-role name="users">
        <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

(this is a setup for WAS 8.0, if you have an older EAR version this file is named ibm-application.xmi and has a different syntax).

If you do not have EAR, it doesn't matter because WAS will ask you to map security role "users" to appropriate user/group or to a special subject "all authenticated users", as in this case.

This mechanism can be used to perform a fine-grained mapping, you can define separate roles for groups and map it to user repository groups etc.

Comment: which login module will it get to ? There are multiple login modules

Comment: Login modules in WAS are chained. Moreover, you can add your custom login module e.g. on DEFAULT and WEB_INBOUND JAAS system login configurations. More about JAAS login configurations can be found on https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/hr/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tsec_jaascustlogmod.html (I see that Gas already answered this).

Comment: I have already created my login module for content navigator and it calls the NAVIGATOR application security module.

However in case of J_Security I am trying to edit the WEB_INBOUND now. 

Thanks